# Stack Overflow Questions and Google Search

Tags: discussion, search, google, technology

How Stack Overflow questions and answers are available in Google search within a minute after posting? Which technology is being used for this both from Stack Overflow and Google side?

Comment: What type of research have you done? Have you read the FAQ?

Comment: @Jon How would the FAQ help here?

Comment: @DannyBeckett Huh.  I had posted that when it was in StackOverflow, not Meta.

Comment: @Jon My apologies, it all makes sense now ;)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I know 2 points which affects:

1. Site with high Page Rank(PR), currently Stackoverflow is having 7/10 pagerank.
   [image]
2. Site which is being updated very frequently is crawled more quickly, indirectly it means that particular site is having latest/updated data, and in this case Stackoverflow is getting infinite number of questions/answers at every second.

Answer (score 2):

If you check in this site http://www.prchecker.info/check_page_rank.php the Page Rank for SO is very high (7).
So i guess Google will have algorithm tweaked to index these types of (Famous) sites fast and show that in results quickly.

Answer (score 1):

Besides normal SEO techniques there's nothing more you can do to affect your result at Google's search engine. It's just that StackOverflow is well constructed and (more than any other thing) well indexed in search engines.